# Не всплывает TPopupMenu у ListBox в Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

TListBox предназначен для показа на форме 3-10 картинок.
Нажимаешь на кнопку Добавить, создается TListBoxItem с TImageViewer.
У TImageViewer HitTest отключен.
TPopupMenu привязано и к TListBoxItem, и к TListBox. По Long tap должно всплывать. Событие Long tap срабатывает, но меню не отображается.

Создаю ListBoxItem

```html
procedure TfmEditObject.AddPhoto(Image: TBitmap);
Var
  item: TListBoxItem;
  imageV: TImageViewer;
begin
  item := TListBoxItem.Create(lbPhotos);
  item.parent := lbPhotos;
  item.text   := '';
  item.Width  := lbPhotos.Width;
  item.PopupMenu := PopupMenu1;

  imageV := TImageViewer.Create(lbPhotos);
  imageV.HitTest := False;
  imageV.Parent  := item;
  imageV.Align   := TAlignLayout.Client;
  imageV.Bitmap.Assign(image);

  item.SetFocus;
end;
```

Событие OnGesture у ListBox`а срабатывает и доходит до строки с показом меню, но меню не всплывает

```html
procedure TfmEditObject.lbPhotosGesture(Sender: TObject;
  const EventInfo: TGestureEventInfo; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  c: IControl;
  ListBox: TListBox;
  lbxPoint: TPointF;
  ListBoxItem: TListBoxItem;
begin
  if EventInfo.GestureID = igiLongTap then
    if (sender is TListBox) and assigned(TListBox(sender).Selected) then
    begin
      c := ObjectAtPoint(EventInfo.Location);
      if Assigned(c) then
        if Assigned(c.GetObject) then
          if c.GetObject is TListBox then
            begin
              ListBox := TListBox(c.GetObject);
              lbxPoint := ListBox.AbsoluteToLocal(EventInfo.Location);

              ListBoxItem := ListBox.ItemByPoint(lbxPoint.X, lbxPoint.Y);
              if Assigned(ListBoxItem) then
              begin
                PopupMenu1.Popup(lbxPoint.X, lbxPoint.Y);
                ShowMessage(FloatToStr(lbxPoint.X) + ':' + FloatToStr(lbxPoint.Y));
              end;
              Handled := True;
            end;
    end;

end;
```

А ShowMessage с координатами всплывает.
Что не так? Как правильно показать контекстное меню?
Delphi 10.1 Upd 2

Comment: ShowMessage своим появлением и перехватом фокуса не закрывает-ли меню?.. Ну и, плюс, не уверен точно насчёт FMX, но в VCL PopupMenu.Popup() требует глобальных координат, а не локальных для элемента.

Comment: А popupmenu в Андроиде вообще способно появляться?

Comment: Понятия не имею и в вопросе нет ни слова про андроид.

Comment: "ShowMessage своим появлением и перехватом фокуса не закрывает-ли меню?"
Нет. Без ShowMessage тоже не всплывает.

Answer (score 0):

Переделываю с использованием TListBox:

https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/creating-an-overflow-menu-on-android-463